# AppLink Xamarin forms not indexing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, applinks

I was wondering if you can help, it's literally driving me crazy. I'm trying to integrate deeplinking into my app following [Lightning lecture](https://github.com/Krumelur/UniversalLinks/tree/master/src/AppLinksDemo) and it simply doesn't work. I can't even get my items to show in spotlight search.

So I created a completely new project, all default New solution->forms app.

The default app is a todo list app, where I've added just two methods

```
AppLinkEntry GetAppLink(ItemDetailViewModel item)
    {
        var pageType = GetType().ToString();
        var pageLink = new AppLinkEntry
        {
            Title = item.Title,
            Description = item.Title,
            AppLinkUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://website1120180225101729.azurewebsites.net/?id={0}",item.Title.Replace(" ","") ), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
            IsLinkActive = true,
            Thumbnail = ImageSource.FromFile("xamarin_logo.png")
        };

        return pageLink;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        appLink = GetAppLink(BindingContext as ItemDetailViewModel);
        if (appLink != null)
        {
            appLink.IsLinkActive = true;
            Application.Current.AppLinks.RegisterLink(appLink);
        }
    }
```

Please see the print screen below. It registers an app link

[image: Breakpoint]

But when I minimise the app and got to spotlight search it doesn't appear there
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also add the `Associated Domains` in your `Entitlements.plist`. Open your `Entitlements.plist` configure it like:

[image]

After setting it, we should add this custom entitlements to our project:

Right click the iOS project => Properties => iOS Bundle Signing => Custom Entitlements.

Choose the `Entitlements.plist` we set above.

Comment: The second bit, custom entitlements to our project: was the issue on my side. Thanks for your answer I figured out a few hours ago, but hopefully this will help some one else